# Two opposing voltage source, of different current capacities?

Tags: voltage, current-source, series

If two voltage source of the same value(20V) are wired in series and they both have different current capacities, could there be any current flow assuming the resistance(internal & circuit) are equal? I assume the voltages being the same and in series to oppose one another they would cancel out regardless of their current capacities?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzkiIK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. No voltage drop across the resistor means that no current will flow through it. This is why cells of the same voltage can be placed in parallel with no bad effects.